# Is it possible to code this website?

Tags: coding-style, windows-forms-designer, graphic, visual-web-developer, programmers-notepad

I'm a Graphic Designer.
I was wondering if it's possible for a programmer to code this website or I should redesign this?

[image: Screen shot]

Because I have doubts about how hard the header and footer are, and I think it's a really hard work for a programmer to code a website like this.
If it's not, please let me know then I will find a developer.

Comment: I would say that the header & footer are going to be hard to impossible do without using large images or tons of code which are going to hurt load times. As a website design I would say that it falls it into the "flyer" design category since it has many elements that are poorly suited to the web format. Thats just my opinion though.

Comment: With you as the designer, I presume you will do the graphics? I don't see what's hard about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is not impossible. It just takes a moment to think it through.

The footer can be made as a background image of the three colour splats which wraps three separate divs (Projects, Products, Contact Us). The header is a series of images absolutely positioned within a relative parent.

This is actually a very simple layout.

Answer (score 0):

The design is bit complex and unusual but not impossible.
It's possible to convert this design in code with use of some script and css hacks mainly position and z-index based hacks